# How can I demonstrate that a weak reference is released?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I am trying to test some code that uses `WeakReference` - how can I force the reference object to be collected so that `reference.Target` returns `null`?

I tried

```
WeakReference reference = new WeakReference(null);
{
    reference.Target = new object();
}

Console.WriteLine(reference.Target);

GC.Collect();
Thread.Sleep(1000);

Console.WriteLine(reference.Target);

Console.ReadLine();
```

but the target is not `null` in both cases. Also tried calling `GC.Collect` multiple times but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Using brackets around `reference.Target = new object();` doesn't make `reference.Target` a garbage. This is why the GarbageCollector won't consider it as garbage

Comment: This doesn't make sense. I run your code exactly as you have it here and the second `Console.WriteLine(reference.Target)` outputs `null` for me.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I just tried running it as release build and it works as you say but under a debug build in Visual Studio, its definitely not null the second time.

Comment: Why do you think it's your job to test core Framework functionality? Weak References do work.

Comment: @Shane - I tried under release and debug modes and got the same results - albirt in LINQPad and not VS. It could be that the debugger in VS is attached and that kept hold of your reference.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - He's not testing the framework. He wants to understand the behaviour he's getting. He's **blaming** the framework, but that's where he went wrong.

Comment: Maybe the code was run within the debugger and the value was used in the Watch or Locals window, making the target referenced by the debugger and preventing the GC from collecting it. Try to run your code without a debugger attached and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Enigmativity  - I traced it to the DEBUG prepossessor symbol, if its defined the object is not collected. Its not that I am blaming the framework for anything I'm sure it works as advertised. I just wanted to simulate the condition of weak reference being released to see if the code I am working on does the right thing. I realize I could simulate this in other ways but then I kind of got curious.

Comment: Also tried running it outside the debugger, it doesn't make any difference, it the compile options that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Run the code in **Release** build (optimisations enabled) and **Start Without Debugging** and the garbage collector well demonstrate the expected behaviour.

The debugger will keep your variables in scope as GC roots in case you need to inspect them.

Also, use the generic version, `WeakReference<T>`. There were problems with API usage for the non-generic that were resolved in the generic one. See: http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2014/08/14/prefer-weakreferencet-to-weakreference/

EDIT: Didn't refresh and notice post was old and comments covered this already.

Answer (score 0):

If one is not interested in the target of a weak reference, but merely want to find out whether it has died, it is better to check whether the `IsAlive` property has become `false` than to check whether the `Target` property has become `null`.  While this may not resolve all issues with debug builds keeping objects alive longer than expected, it will avoid some other issues that could arise, especially when using concurrent garbage collection.  The target of a `WeakReference` cannot be collected while any strong reference exists, and thus getting the `Target` of a `WeakReference` will at least temporarily guard the object in question against being collected.  This may be unavoidable in some cases where code would actually want to do something with the reference in question, but there is no reason to risk prolonging the life of an object if one is merely trying to find out when it dies.

Comment: Use of `IsAlive` is actually the problem Ben Watson identifies with `WeakReference` http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2014/08/14/prefer-weakreferencet-to-weakreference/

Comment: @BenHall: If code wants to *do something* with the target of a weak reference, one should just use the `Target` property and not bother with `IsAlive`.  In cases where one doesn't want to do anything with the object while it is alive, but instead wants to take some action when nothing is "interested" in the object anymore, one should avoid forming any strong references to the object.